# Solving monkey and banana with BFS algorithm

Tags: java, breadth-first-search

I try to solve the monkey and banana problem with the BFS algorithm with java. Here is my code so far

```
public class Program {
    static final int[][] states={
            { 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, //0  | 0 0 0 |
            { 1, 4, 3, 4, 0, 0 }, //1  | 0 1 0 |
            { 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, //2  | 1 0 0 |
            { 0, 4, 0, 0, 3, 1 }, //3  | 0 1 1 |
            { 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0 }, //4  | 1 0 1 |
            { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1 }, //5  | 0 0 1 |
    };
    static final String[] lblStates={
            "0 0 0",
            "0 1 0",
            "1 0 0",
            "0 1 1",
            "1 0 1",
            "0 0 1"
    };

    static class Node{
        public Node parent;
        public int node;

        Node(int node, Node parent) {
            this.node = node;
            this.parent = parent;
        }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return this.node.equals(((Node)obj).node);
    }
    }



    static void BFS(Node start, Node goal) throws InterruptedException {
        if (start.equals(goal)){
            PrintPath(start);
            return;
        }

        Queue<Node> open = new Queue<Node>();
        open.enqueue(start);
        HashSet<Node> closed = new HashSet<Node>();

        while (!open.isEmpty()){
            Node x = open.dequeue();
            List<Node> successorsOfX = GetChildrenOf(x);
            closed.add(x);


            for (Node successor: successorsOfX) {
                if (successor.equals(goal)){
                    PrintPath(successor);
                    System.out.println();
                    return;
                }else if(!closed.contains(successor) && !open.equals(successor)){
                    open.enqueue(successor);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    static void PrintPath(Node node){
        if (node.parent != null){
            PrintPath(node.parent);
            System.out.println(lblStates[node.node]);
        }else {
            System.out.println(lblStates[node.node]);
        }
    }

    static List<Node> GetChildrenOf(Node parent){
        List<Node> result = new ArrayList<Node>();
        for (int i = 0; i <states.length ; i++) {
            int[] cost=states[parent.node];
            if (!cost.equals(0)){
                Node newNode = new Node(i, parent);
                result.add(newNode);
                System.out.print(cost[i]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        return result;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        int start = 0;
        int goal = 4;

        BFS(new Node(start, null), new Node(goal, null));
    }
}
```

The conditions are (A1,A2,A3)

1. A1 -> see if the monkey is on the box
2. A2 -> see if the monkey is near the box
3. A3 -> see if the box is under the banana

Start condition (0,0,0), Final condition (1,0,1)
In the end the result it has to be the path for the monkey

- 0 0 0
  0 1 0
  0 1 1
  1 0 1

But every time i run the program it get stuck in endless loop and doesn't print the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In class `Node`, instead of `public int node;`, try using `public Integer node;`.

Or, change `return this.node.equals(((Node)obj).node);` to `return this.node == ((Node)obj).node;`

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem may be that since you are creating new children node instances in the **GetChildrenOf(...)** method, your **closedSet** never registers as containing the successors (because HashSet uses the default equals() method if there isn't one defined, and the two instances are not the same because you create new child node instances.  So the method just keeps on adding the successors over and over and goes indefinitely.

You should try implementing an equals() method in the Node class and see if that fixes it.

Good luck!

Comment: I try to implement in the equals(Object obj) a return this.node.equals(((Node)obj).node); but it says that cannot resolve method equals(int)